# If ARM compiler has similar option for -Werror

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, armcc

I know `gcc` has an option `-Werror`, which can stop compile if there is an warning, if `armcc` has similar option, because I want to have a good code quality control in compile level

**additional info:**

I use `armcc` 2.2 build 616, I consult ARM, it said `--diag_error=warning` was add ONLY for `armcc` 4.0 or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from ARM, use following

```
--diag_error=[warning/error_refer_number]
```

for example:

```
--diag_error=179,180
```

Since ARM add `--diag_error=warning` for `armcc` 4.0 or later, for old `armcc`, I ONLY can specify which warning number will STOP the compile process

Answer (score 0):

Try `--diag_error=warning`.
See http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ARMCCREF/armccref_CHDJDADE.htm.

Best,
Tim

Comment: thanks for you info, I add this flag into makefile, but it pop up `"no source": Error: command-line:  #613: invalid error tag in diagnostic control option: warning`

Comment: Check your version of armcc: "With build 650 and later of RVCT 4.0, you can also use --diag_error=warning, which will cause all warnings to be upgraded to errors." (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka14423.html). You may have a build < 650.

Comment: many thanks for you info, I just use `armcc` 2.2, how can I overcome? I also ask ARM, they said this compiler feature was add in `armcc` 4.0 or later